# Redux "create entity" state structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have a component *documents* with a button, which *onClick* calls an action **createDocument**. The action returns a payload (on success) with **id** of the new document and then we have to route to the newly created document route */documents/:id*

Now the way I have set it up right now, is not by using the Redux state at all, but simply by using the promise in the component to get the action and then making the route change.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createDocument } from 'actions/documents';

@connect(null, { createDocument })
export default class Documents extends Component {
  handleCreateClick () {
    this.props.createDocument().then((action) => {
      const { payload } = action;

      browserHistory.push(`documents/${payload.id}`);
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleCreateClick}>
          Create
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But again: this is not using the Redux state to handle errors, or anything. What would be the most "standard" way of handling such situation in Redux? I feel like putting the "new" id on the state would be overkill and way more boilerplate code.

Comment: Standard way of handling such situation in Redux is dispatch `createDocument` and check for document id in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: @elmeister Thanks for the answer, I know that is the way to handle this in the Redux way, but don't you think this is overkill here?